# 2002 Vauxhall Astra Diesel Part help?

Tags: engine, part-identification, vauxhall, astra

Can anyone tell me what the part in the red circle is called ? - My engine seems to be missing it all of a sudden (last time I let my Wife borrow the car!)

Many thanks

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: PCV valve / assembly, at least part of the ventilation system connected to the air intake between the air filter and the inlet manifold.